# Ошибка при создании проекта CLR

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Когда создаю проект CLR, добавляю Windows Forms, добавляю код, перезахожу, компилирую и выводится ошибка: 
`Ошибка C1070   непарные #if/#endif в файле "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h"    CTool   C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h  22764`

При нажатии на ошибку, открывается файл winnt.h и появляются следующие ошибки:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Переустановил пакет SDK для Windows. Помогло решить проблему